# Implementing interface issue

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have a type hint in the constructor but for some reason I get

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Log::__construct() must be an instance of TestInterface, instance of Log\Handler given, called in
```

TestInterface.php

```
namespace Log;  
    interface TestInterface
    {
      public function log();
    }
```

Handler.php

```
namespace Log;

require_once 'TestInterface.php';

use Log\TestInterface;

    class Handler implements TestInterface 
    {
      public function log() 
      {
        //some logic goes here 
      }
    }
```

Log.php

```
require_once 'Handler.php';

use Log\Handler;
class Log 
{
  public function __construct(TestInterface $handler)
  {
    $handler->log('test');
  }
}

$obj = new Log(new Handler());
```

So why do I get this error? I thought that when I implement the TestInterface the instance of Handler class will be passed through the Log constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `use Log\TestInterface;` to the top of Log.php, because TestInterface is undefined in the global namespace.  What you got back was not a helpful error message at all, but this should do it:

```
require_once 'Handler.php';

use Log\Handler;
use Log\TestInterface;

class Log 
{
  public function __construct(TestInterface $handler)
  {
    $handler->log('test');
  }
}

$obj = new Log(new Handler());
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the job. Is there an another solution of the problem?

Comment: @MZON I truly don't think so, but I'm here to learn as well and am open to ideas :).  The problem would've been clearer if it said 'TestInterface is not defined' instead of how it's currently described  as 'Argument 1 must be an instance of a class/interface that doesn't exist'